# Postfix/MySQL: Unknown User Error

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix, email-server

I just followed this excellent tutorial on [setting up a mail server with Postfix/Dovecot/etc](http://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/).

I got through it, and I can send email just fine.  The domain I'm using is `jonah.name`.  However, I cannot receive emails from external emails or other internal mailboxes.  If I try to send an email to a user in it, I get a "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" email back, telling me **that the user is unknown**.  This is what comes up in `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Aug 17 21:31:27 localhost postfix/smtpd[810]: connect from gateway09.websitewelcome.com[69.93.179.27]
Aug 17 21:31:28 localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[816]: warning: do not list domain jonah.name in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Aug 17 21:31:28 localhost postgrey[27058]: action=pass, reason=triplet found, client_name=gateway09.websitewelcome.com, client_address=69.93.179.27, sender=jonah@nucleussystems.com, recipient=jonah@jonah.name
Aug 17 21:31:28 localhost postfix/smtpd[810]: 79B1D38947: client=gateway09.websitewelcome.com[69.93.179.27]
Aug 17 21:31:28 localhost postfix/cleanup[819]: 79B1D38947: message-id=<502EB82E.5030406@nucleussystems.com>
Aug 17 21:31:28 localhost postfix/qmgr[732]: 79B1D38947: from=<jonah@nucleussystems.com>, size=1634, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 17 21:31:28 localhost postfix/smtpd[810]: disconnect from gateway09.websitewelcome.com[69.93.179.27]
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/smtpd[826]: connect from remotebox[127.0.0.1]
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[816]: warning: do not list domain jonah.name in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/smtpd[826]: 622BF3894A: client=remotebox[127.0.0.1]
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/cleanup[819]: 622BF3894A: message-id=<502EB82E.5030406@nucleussystems.com>
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/smtpd[826]: disconnect from remotebox[127.0.0.1]
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/qmgr[732]: 622BF3894A: from=<jonah@nucleussystems.com>, size=2050, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[816]: warning: do not list domain jonah.name in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost amavis[30938]: (30938-10) Passed CLEAN, [69.93.179.27] <jonah@nucleussystems.com> -> <jonah@jonah.name>, Message-ID: <502EB82E.5030406@nucleussystems.com>, mail_id: jbjlO+jljnPM, Hits: -0.001, size: 1634, queued_as: 622BF3894A, 1855 ms
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/smtp[821]: 79B1D38947: to=<jonah@jonah.name>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=2.3, delays=0.41/0.01/0/1.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA([127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 622BF3894A)
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/qmgr[732]: 79B1D38947: removed
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/local[827]: 622BF3894A: to=<jonah@jonah.name>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "jonah")
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/cleanup[819]: 65CAF38953: message-id=<20120817213130.65CAF38953@jonah.name>
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/bounce[828]: 622BF3894A: sender non-delivery notification: 65CAF38953
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/qmgr[732]: 65CAF38953: from=<>, size=3832, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/qmgr[732]: 622BF3894A: removed
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/smtp[829]: 65CAF38953: to=<jonah@nucleussystems.com>, relay=mail.nucleussystems.com[50.116.72.68]:25, delay=0.46, delays=0/0.01/0.33/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1T2U8g-0008VP-Qb)
Aug 17 21:31:30 localhost postfix/qmgr[732]: 65CAF38953: removed
```

The log confirms (line 18) that the user is "unknown".  I re-double-checked all of the configuration files that connect to MySQL, but I couldn't find any flaws.  Here are the MySQL virtual configuration files:

```
# /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf

user = mail
password = **password**
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mail
query = SELECT goto FROM alias,alias_domain
  WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d'
  AND alias.address=concat('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain)
  AND alias.active = 1

# /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf

user = mail
password = **password**
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mail
table = alias
select_field = goto
where_field = address
additional_conditions = and active = '1'

# /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domain_maps.cf

user = mail
password = **password**
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mail
table = domain
select_field = domain
where_field = domain
additional_conditions = and backupmx = '0' and active = '1'

# /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domainaliases_maps.cf

user = mail
password = **password**
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mail
query = SELECT maildir FROM mailbox, alias_domain
  WHERE alias_domain.alias_domain = '%d'
  AND mailbox.username=concat('%u', '@', alias_domain.target_domain )
  AND mailbox.active = 1

# /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

user = mail
password = **password**
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mail
table = mailbox
select_field = CONCAT(domain, '/', local_part)
where_field = username
additional_conditions = and active = '1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't Answer in the log above?
"warning: do not list domain jonah.name in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains"

Edit :

Try "mydestination = localhost"

"mydestination : The list of domains that are delivered via the $local_transport mail delivery transport." ie postfix tried to find a real user called jonah. According to your setup, you want user jonah to be virtual, so jonah.name must not be part of mydestination (I agree, it's tricky).

Comment: It's just a warning, so I don't think so.  It goes right past it without any other problems.  Interestingly enough, I commented out the `mydestination` directive in `main.cf` and restarted the service, but it still gives that error.

Comment: try "mydestination = localhost"

Comment: THAT FIXED IT!!!!!! You, sir, are a boss.

Comment: So why is that?  What does the `mydestination` directive do that it would cause that problem?

Comment: When you commented out the mydestination line, it falled back on default value, which is likely to include jonah.name

Comment: But why does having `jonah.name` mess it up?  What action is using that that must have `localhost`?

Comment: "mydestination : The list of domains that are delivered via the $local_transport mail delivery transport." ie postfix tried to find a real user called jonah. According to your setup, you want user jonah to be virtual, so jonah.name must not be part of mydestination (I agree, it's tricky).

Comment: Great, thank you.  My first time setting up a mail server, I'm pretty happy.  14 hours later, here I am! :)  _You could just make your own edit?_

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sender is greylisted, if the sender retry after about 300 seconds it is supposed to pass. You can also disable the greylisting.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I disabled greylisting and I updated the error log.  It says the user is unknown, so I guess there's an issue connecting to MySQL.

Comment: Sorry can't help much, I'm also using postfix/dovecot/greylist etc but not in virtual mode!

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway Alex.  At least I'm getting closer, I know it's a problem with accessing the user list.